# What is the etiquette for keeping/discarding a contributor's namespace in pull requests?

Tags: github, namespaces, pull-request

I have a Github project repository.  A contributor forked the repository, added a new file and sent me a pull request.

I noticed that he used his own namespace in that (.java) file, whereas the rest of my project uses my own namespace.

Aesthetically I would like all files in my repository to use my namespace.  However, this is code that he wrote and is his contribution.

What is the best etiquette or course of action here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using your package naming to maintain consistency and allow this contributor credit via `@author` in the Javadoc. Allowing contributors to use their own naming might get messy. If you have a package, say `dao` to contain all your Data Access Objects, and several contributors, you probably don't want to end up with `net.smith.john.dao`, `net.hunt.anthony.dao`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Using @author seems like the way to go.